# Bracket syntax in Ramda replace function

Tags: javascript, replace, ramda.js

I've used JavaScript for quite a long time, yet am struggling to understand how [this example from the Ramda docs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#__) works:

> ```
> const greet = R.replace('{name}', R.__, 'Hello, {name}!');
> greet('Alice'); //=> 'Hello, Alice!'
> ```

How is the `{name}` variable/match recognized and then later interpolated into the `Hello, {name}` string?  Is this a Ramda feature? A JavaScript trick? I've never seen this pattern before.

I checked the Ramda `replace` source code and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Mulan's answer is great.  And a really simple way to think of it is for some function `const fn =  (a, b, c) => ??`,  `R.curry (fn) (1, R.__, 3) (2) //=> f (1, 2, 3)`.  In this case `replace` has been curried by a similar Ramda-internal manner.  The currying allows you to supply any initial sequence of the arguments and await the rest.  The placeholder allows you to supply an arbitrary subset of the arguments and await the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special going on with `{name}` or `replace`. `R.__` creates a partially applied function where the argument in that position is supplied later.

It might help to see it written this way-

```js
const greet = R.replace('{name}', R.__, 'Hello, {name}!');

const greet = function(replacement) {
  return R.replace('{name}', replacement, 'Hello, {name}!')
}
```

You can see it working here without the `R.replace` function -

```js
const stringReplace = R.curry((pattern, replacement, s) =>
  s.replace(pattern, replacement) // String.prototype.replace
)

const greet = stringReplace("***", R.__, "hello ***")
console.log(greet("world")) // hello world
console.log(greet("earth")) // hello earth
```

The "magic" of `R.__` is made possible because every function in the Ramda library is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) with its `curry` helper. A curried function waits for all of its arguments before it is finally applied and `R.__` allows you to apply arguments out of position.

Comment: It's embarrassing the curried nature of the expression confused me into overlooking the simple fact that it's more or less just this: 'Hello, {name}!'.replace('{name}', replacement). Thank you

Comment: @Javiliano don't be embarrassed! `R.__` is used to enable a particular _style_, called [tacit programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) or _point-free style_. It's popular amongst functional style programmers but it's a foreign concept in other styles.

Answer (score 2):

> I checked the Ramda `replace` source code and couldn't find anything.

You probably overlooked it, because it's there.

[`source/replace.js`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.28.0/source/replace.js#L28-L30)

> ```
> var replace = _curry3(function replace(regex, replacement, str) {
>   return str.replace(regex, replacement);
> });
> ```

Note that the function is wrapped in `_curry3()` which handles the currying/placeholders.

[`source/internal/_curry3.js`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.28.0/source/internal/_curry3.js#L14-L49)

> ```
> export default function _curry3(fn) {
>   return function f3(a, b, c) {
>     switch (arguments.length) {
>       case 0:
>         return f3;
>       case 1:
>         return _isPlaceholder(a)
>           ? f3
>           : _curry2(function(_b, _c) { return fn(a, _b, _c); });
>       case 2:
>         return _isPlaceholder(a) && _isPlaceholder(b)
>           ? f3
>           : _isPlaceholder(a)
>             ? _curry2(function(_a, _c) { return fn(_a, b, _c); })
>             : _isPlaceholder(b)
>               ? _curry2(function(_b, _c) { return fn(a, _b, _c); })
>               : _curry1(function(_c) { return fn(a, b, _c); });
>       default:
>         return _isPlaceholder(a) && _isPlaceholder(b) && _isPlaceholder(c)
>           ? f3
>           : _isPlaceholder(a) && _isPlaceholder(b)
>             ? _curry2(function(_a, _b) { return fn(_a, _b, c); })
>             : _isPlaceholder(a) && _isPlaceholder(c)
>               ? _curry2(function(_a, _c) { return fn(_a, b, _c); })
>               : _isPlaceholder(b) && _isPlaceholder(c)
>                 ? _curry2(function(_b, _c) { return fn(a, _b, _c); })
>                 : _isPlaceholder(a)
>                   ? _curry1(function(_a) { return fn(_a, b, c); })
>                   : _isPlaceholder(b)
>                     ? _curry1(function(_b) { return fn(a, _b, c); })
>                     : _isPlaceholder(c)
>                       ? _curry1(function(_c) { return fn(a, b, _c); })
>                       : fn(a, b, c);
>     }
>   };
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Mulan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183/mulan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75733342/7575111) I just wanted to add that this isn't any special variable or "official templating syntax". It's a pretty straight forward replacement. You define what's going to be replace. e.g. this works just the same:

```js
const greet = R.replace('My_CustomName123', R.__, 'Hello, My_CustomName123');
```

No JS magic. Just a simple [`replace`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.28.0/source/replace.js#L29)